# Replace the character on sentence by white space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have sentences string contains this character (X.V) X variable and i want replace this (X.V) by white space i do that :
`preg_replace("/\([^)]+/","",$string);` in function `($string)` but not worked

original: `$string=3 mail under (2.44) on 10 examples 1 CArd A2 (4.99)`
ouput: `$string= 3 mail under   on 10 examples 1 card A 2`

Comment: Post the expected output and the original string too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression `preg_replace("/\([^)]+/","",$string);` replaces opening parenthesis and all character that is not a closing parenthesis by nothing.

But you want to replace something like `(X.V)` by space, you could do:

```
preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/", " ", $string);
```

In action:

```
$string = "3 mail under (2.44) on 10 examples 1 CArd A2 (4.99)";
$string = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/", " ", $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
3 mail under   on 10 examples 1 CArd A2
```

Comment: yes i do that on function($string){preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/", " ", $string);}when i call function i have nothing?

Comment: @test: It works, see my edit. Or show us the script (relevant part) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace a particular character then, try

> [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace("(X.V)"," ",$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

if x and v are character and you want replace it by white space then you could use str_replace() function.put X,V into  array and

```
$arr = array(X,V);
$string = str_replace($arr , '',$string);
```